# Something wrong with import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

i want to run a existing project.but when i imported the `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar`,the error occurred.

```
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
```

i can't find `AndroidHttpTransport` method in package `org.ksoap2.transport`.
how can i deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

AndroidHttpTransport is deprecated...for more info on this change, check out this link: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2ksoap/issues/detail?id=2

You will see that there is also a solution to fix the code if it already exists in your project by this replacement:

```
AndroidHttpTransport ht = new AndroidHttpTransport(Address);
androidHttpTransport.call(params.GetSoapAction(), envelope);
```

to:

```
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Address);
ht.call(params.GetSoapAction(), envelope);
```

Comment: 2nd line should be 'ht.call' not 'HttpTransportSE.call'

Answer (score 1):

You should use ksoap2 jar file..
And then use following code

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
SoapObject response=null;
try
{
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar. Then the error will remove.

Comment: What do you mean by importing a jar file? Do you mean compile? A meaningless answer.

Answer (score 0):

copy the jar file (ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar) to lib folder and then refresh lib folder from eclipse